# Call Rcpp c++ function from R code in the same package

Tags: r, rcpp, r-package

I want to build an Rcpp package with C++ and R code. With the C++ code only (R code removed), everything compiles and works nicely and after building and loading the exported functions are callable as expected as

```
<packageName>::<functionName>()
```

However, when including the R code with the call to the C++ code, I get an object not found error when building the package:

```
R CMD build <packageName>
[...]
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in <functionName>() :
  object '_<packageName>_<functionName>' not found
Error: unable to load R code in package '<packageName>'
```

The error happens after the C++ code is successfully compiled.

```
<functionName>()
```

is mapped to

```
_<packageName>_<functionName>
```

in `R/RcppExports.R` as usual, but it does not appear that it can be loaded by the R code at build time.

The structure of the package is as usual:

```
<packageName>
├── DESCRIPTION
├── man
│   ├── <functionName>.rd
│   └── <packageName>-package.rd
├── NAMESPACE
├── R
│   ├── <RCodeFileName>.R
│   └── RcppExports.R   
├── README.md
└── src
    ├── <C++CodeFileName>.cpp
    ├── <C++CodeFileName>.o
    ├── <packageName>.so
    ├── RCppExports.cpp
    ├── RCppExports.o
    └── symbols.rds
```

where the `.o` and `.so` files are produced when compiling the package.

The R file calls the function from the C++ file directly:

```
[other stuff]
[...]
<functionName>()
```

`NAMESPACE` file is also as usual:

```
useDynLib(<packageName>, .registration=TRUE)
importFrom(Rcpp, evalCpp)
exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")
```

This seems like a very simple and straight forward problem (calling C++ code from R code in an Rcpp package). Nevertheless, I seem to be unable to find any indication of how this should be done.

**Edit (Apr 8 2020): `build` vs. `INSTALL`**

The problem will occur in every case for

```
R CMD INSTALL <packageName>_<version>.tar.gz
```

If the included help file

```
man/<packageName>-package.Rd
```

is built so that it forces `installing the package to process help pages` the error will already occur in

```
R CMD build <packageName>
```

as described above.

**Edit (Apr 8 2020): Steps to reproduce with `Rcpp.package.skeleton()` (on Unix-like systems anyway)**

```
Rscript -e 'Rcpp::Rcpp.package.skeleton("demo20200408")'
echo 'rcpp_hello_world()' > errorDemo/R/example.R
R CMD INSTALL errorDemo
```

Comment: What would free-standing code like that do? What would receive it result? Who or what would call it?  It makes little sense. Package startup code is better understood, can be place in `.onLoad()` and `.onAttach()` and can of course use Rcpp-driven code from the same package.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: Explained in comment to your answer below: I have to make my package use a library explicitly in R code. This library is used in `@example`'s to my C++ functions. If I either do not explicitly use it in R code but include it in the DESCRIPTION file or if I do not include it in the DESCRIPTION file at all, various compilers throw warnings, which I cannot have. I therefore wanted to include the example code as an R script. But you are right and it makes sense to me that it should be in a function then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to slow dowm.  The Rcpp package itself *comes with a demo package generator* via the `Rcpp.package.skeleton()` function.  Run it!

The compare piece by piece to what you have.

A second generator is *e.g.* built into RStudio and available under the File -> New Project -> New directory -> Package with Rcpp menu options.

Otherwise, hard to tell.  Did you do anything funky to you function name?  Because these are mapped to R *and* C++ you have restrictions from both. *I.e.* you cannot use a dot (as that would be a class method notation in C++).

Lastly, even when *unexported* the C++ function should be available from the installed and loaded package via three colons, *i.e.* `mypkg:::myFun()`.

Lastly, quick demo:

**Create it**

```
edd@rob:/tmp$ Rscript -e 'Rcpp::Rcpp.package.skeleton("demo20200408")'
Creating directories ...
Creating DESCRIPTION ...
Creating NAMESPACE ...
Creating Read-and-delete-me ...
Saving functions and data ...
Making help files ...
Done.
Further steps are described in './demo20200408/Read-and-delete-me'.

Adding Rcpp settings
 >> added Imports: Rcpp
 >> added LinkingTo: Rcpp
 >> added useDynLib directive to NAMESPACE
 >> added importFrom(Rcpp, evalCpp) directive to NAMESPACE
 >> added example src file using Rcpp attributes
 >> added Rd file for rcpp_hello_world
 >> compiled Rcpp attributes 
edd@rob:/tmp$
```

**Install it**

```
edd@rob:/tmp$ R CMD INSTALL demo20200408 
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *source* package ‘demo20200408’ ...
** using staged installation
** libs
ccache g++ -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
ccache g++ -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic  -c rcpp_hello_world.cpp -o rcpp_hello_world.o
ccache g++ -Wl,-S -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o demo20200408.so RcppExports.o rcpp_hello_world.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/00LOCK-demo20200408/00new/demo20200408/libs
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
** checking absolute paths in shared objects and dynamic libraries
** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
* DONE (demo20200408)
edd@rob:/tmp$
```

**Run it**

```
edd@rob:/tmp$ Rscript -e 'library(demo20200408); rcpp_hello_world()'
[[1]]
[1] "foo" "bar"

[[2]]
[1] 0 1

edd@rob:/tmp$
```

**And add an R function and call it too**

```
edd@rob:/tmp$ echo 'r_hello_world <- function() cat("hi there\n")' > demo20200408/R/foo.R
edd@rob:/tmp$ R CMD INSTALL demo20200408 
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *source* package ‘demo20200408’ ...
** using staged installation
** libs
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/00LOCK-demo20200408/00new/demo20200408/libs
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
** checking absolute paths in shared objects and dynamic libraries
** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
* DONE (demo20200408)
edd@rob:/tmp$ Rscript -e 'library(demo20200408); r_hello_world()'
hi there
edd@rob:/tmp$
```

Still no issue despite OP's claims

In the most recent comment below it is claimed that the generated function cannot be called.  That is false.

```
edd@rob:/tmp$ editor demo20200408/R/foo.R    # subst. fave editor here
edd@rob:/tmp$ cat demo20200408/R/foo.R 
r_hello_world <- function() {
        cat("hi there\n")
        ignored <- rcpp_hello_world()
        NULL
}
edd@rob:/tmp$ R CMD INSTALL demo20200408 
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *source* package ‘demo20200408’ ...
** using staged installation
** libs
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/00LOCK-demo20200408/00new/demo20200408/libs
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
** checking absolute paths in shared objects and dynamic libraries
** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
* DONE (demo20200408)
edd@rob:/tmp$ Rscript -e 'library(demo20200408); r_hello_world()'
hi there
NULL
edd@rob:/tmp$
```

Comment: Thank you. As far as I can see, `Rcpp.package.skeleton()` builds a package without any R code besides the `RcppExports.R`. As I said, this part works for me too. The problem is in the R code.

Comment: I never use it that way but if you read the (available) help for `package.skeleton()` (which we call) then you will see that it shows how to create a skeleton from an existing R function or file.  Apart from that, you can use the `cp` command or an editor to add an R file to your directory---so I don't quite see where the constraint is.

Comment: Thank you. Thanks also for adding the example with an R function. However, if you call `rcpp_hello_world()` from your R script (even if that is the only line in the R script), your `R CMD INSTALL (packageName)_(version).tar.gz` command will fail as described above. (Note: `R CMD build (packageName)` will also fail if `man/packageName-package.Rd` forces `installing the package to process help pages`; this was my case described in the OP.)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this (see another edit), and we're going in circles. You claim something does work, I cannot understand what you appear to imply. _In any event this not the venue for bug reports_.  GitHub, and if you have a reproducible issue maybe you can file it there.

Comment: So you are saying the code must be placed in a function in the R script, so that it is not executed when the compiler reads the script? This makes sense to me.

Comment: I am saying it has to be a valid R package --- in order to be a valid R package.  Like the ones we build from the generator.  Like the over 1900 on CRAN. Are you maybe having the wrong mental model of what a package is, or should be?   Sadly computers play by certain rules.  And I think I have little further to add here.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. I do not think I am confused as to what a package is or what rules computers play by. I just have to make my package use a library explicitly in R code. This library is used in `@example`'s to my C++ functions. If I either do not explicitly use it in R code but include it in the DESCRIPTION file or if I do not include it in the DESCRIPTION file at all, various compilers throw warnings, which I cannot have. I therefore wanted to include the example code as an R script. But you are right and it makes sense to me that it should be in a function then. Just wanted to explain.